# Get column names from a table matching a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named TableA which has many rows. Sample structure given below

```
CID int, Col1 int, Col2 int, Col3 int, Col4 int
```

when I run a query (say when CID=5) i will get only one row with Col1,Col2 etc having different values.

I want to get the digit of column name where the row value is -1.

For more clarity

```
CID, Col1, Col2 , Col3 , Col4 
5      0    -1     0       -1
```

in this example i should get result as

```
MyRes
2
4
```

Is there a any way to achieve it

Comment: You could do it using a series of CASE statements.

Comment: select * from (
SELECT CASE
WHEN Col1= '-1' THEN 'Col1'
WHEN Col2= '-1' THEN 'Col2'
......
END AS MyRes
FROM TableA 
)

But this will give u Col2 only

Comment: SachuMine, you can use the [edit] link below the question to add information to it, directly - that's better than putting useful information in a comment. People need to see what you've tried and *how* it's not working in order to correctly process the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `unpivot` then filter your record on basis of result value which is `-1` in your case.

```
; with cte as (
select CID, result, col from
(
   select * from table 
) as t
unpivot
(
   result for col in ( Col1, col2, col3, col4 )
) as p
)
select CId, col from cte where result = -1
```

Just a bit of homework for you to get the number part from the column name.
In case you find any problem in that part please comment I'll do that also but lets give a try first.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
declare @ID int
set @ID = 1
select substring( T1.ColName, 2, LEN(T1.ColName)) as MyRes from (
select
  Col.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(10)') as ColName
from (select *
      from TableA

      for xml path(''), type) as T(XMLCol)
  cross apply 
    T.XMLCol.nodes('*') as n(Col) 
where Col.value('.', 'varchar(10)') = '-1'  
)T1
```